# JQuery plugin start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery

t'm creating a jQuery plugin and i found this code from another what it means

```
(function() {
  (function($) {

**code here**

 return this;
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask a good question. In your case you are better of searching the web on how to create a jquery plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-executing anonymous function in JS. It is called [iife](/questions/tagged/iife) (In Javascript, an IIFE stands for an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression: a function expression that gets invoked immediately after it is defined, such as `(function(){ /* code */ })();`)

1. `(function() { ... })`: This function defeinition (IIFE) creates a
   new scope, which helps prevent naming conflicts with other code on
   the page.
2. `(function($) { ... })(jQuery)`: This is another IIFE that takes in
   the jQuery object as a parameter and passes it in as an argument
   when the function is invoked. Thanks to this, you can use `$` as a
   shorthand alias for jQuery.
3. `return this;`: This line returns the current value of `this`. In
   this context, it's returning the plugin object itself.
4. `}).call(this);`: This line invokes the IIFE from step 1, but with
   the this value set to the global object. This is done to ensure that
   the plugin works correctly in both the browser and server
   environments.